# Как дописать данные в уже существующий бинарный файл C#

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться как дописать данные в бинарный файл ? 
Есть код который записывает значение в файл :

```
using (BinaryWriter WriteNr = new BinaryWriter(
    File.Open(
        path2, 
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
        FileAccess.Write, 
        FileShare.ReadWrite
    )
))
{
    WriteNr.Write(Line);

    WriteNr.Close();
}
```

Но при добавлении новой записи, старая стирается, тоесть файл перезаписывается, как сделать что бы старые записи сохранялись а новые добавлялись ? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

При чтении файла все равно попадают только последние данные, вот как читаю файл:

```
using (BinaryReader reader2 = new BinaryReader(
    File.Open(
              path2, 
              FileMode.Open, 
              FileAccess.Read, 
              FileShare.ReadWrite
              )
)) 
{ 
      while (reader.PeekChar() > -1) 
     { Nr++; Line = reader.ReadInt32();}
```

Тоесть мне нужно от начала до конца прочитать и если нет совпадений записать, а проверить я не могу потому как данные постоянно берутся последние записанные, а не по порядку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смени `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` на `FileMode.Append` и будет дозапись.

Пример дозаписи:

```
private static void AppendData(string filename, int intData, string stringData, byte[] lotsOfData)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        bw.Write(intData);
        bw.Write(stringData);
        bw.Write(lotsOfData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но не помогло при чтении файла, всеравно попадают последние записанные данные

Comment: `using (BinaryReader reader2 = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
                    {
                        while (reader.PeekChar() > -1) 
                        {
                            Nr++;

                            Line = reader.ReadInt32();}` Так происходит чтение из файла

Comment: @Ethernets, дополни лучше вопрос.

Comment: @Ethernets, и у тебя FileMode.Open, а нужен Append.

Comment: тогда получаю исключение что сочетание FileMode.Append  и FileAccess.Read недопустимы

Comment: @Ethernets, не заметил, что ты приводишь код для чтения. Ты уверен, что у тебя что-то другое не затирает файл? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398418/how-append-data-to-a-binary-file Вот пример Append'a

Comment: Убрал полностью FileMode и Access и получаю исключение поток был недоступен для чтения

Comment: пересоздал заново фал все заработало, большое вам спасибо.